# BuddyPress avatar showing up outside designated content

Tags: php, wordpress, buddypress

I have a BuddyPress member loop that includes the user avatar. The avatar is showing up, but outside it's wrapping html element.

```
if ( bp_has_members( bp_ajax_querystring( 'members' ) ) ) :

      $content.="<ul>";

      while ( bp_members() ) : bp_the_member();

      $content.="<li><a href='".bp_member_permalink()."'>".bp_member_avatar()."</a></li>";

   endwhile;

   $content.="</ul>";

else:

   $content.='You are not connected to any companies.';

endif;
```

The result is showing up with empty

```
<ul>
  <li></li>
</ul>
```

And the avatars are there, but above the actual list.

[image]

Any help would be great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This function will echo the avatar: `bp_member_avatar()`.
So it will appear as your code runs, rather than append it to `$content`.
Try using `bp_get_member_avatar()` instead.